# how to send mail with mvcMailer on host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcmailer

how to send mail with mvcMailer on host www.mywindowshosting.com ?

I am using the following code :

UserMailer class :

```
  public class UserMailer : MailerBase, IUserMailer
    {
        public UserMailer()
        {
            MasterName = "_Layout";
        }

        public MvcMailMessage ForgetPassword(EmailForgetPasswordViewModel forgetPasswordViewModel)
        {
            ViewData.Model = forgetPasswordViewModel;
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.BodyTransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
                x.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                x.Subject = forgetPasswordViewModel.Subject;
                x.ViewName = forgetPasswordViewModel.ViewName;
                x.To.Add(forgetPasswordViewModel.To);
            });
        }
    }
```

interface  :

```
 public interface IUserMailer
    {
        MvcMailMessage ForgetPassword(EmailForgetPasswordViewModel forgetPasswordViewModel);
    }
```

action :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[MyValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> ForgotPassword(ForgetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _userMailer.ForgetPassword(new EmailForgetPasswordViewModel
         {
             To = model.Email,
             Url = callbackUrl
         }).SendAsync();
        return SuccessSendMail();
    }
    return ModelState.GetListOfErrors();
}
```

output : `Request was sent successfully`. The output is correct but does not send email.

**`Note`** :  The code works correctly on the `localhost` And e-mail will be sent. but When the project is publish on `www.mywindowshosting.com` E-mail not be sent but output : `Request was sent successfully`

**update :**

```
    <smtp from="myMail@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myMail@gmail.com" password="myPassword" />
    </smtp>
```

Comment: Have you configured smtp server credentials in `web.config` file?

Comment: update question. please see the `Note`. The code works correctly on the localhost And e-mail will be sent.

Comment: If this code works locally well. This means your host blocked 587 port. Ask your provider.